# Which music genre is that (Far Away von Tristam, Baken)?

Tags: identify-this-genre

Can someone identify thes music genre of the song?
**But only the first 42 seconds!**
It would be great, if someone know it :)

Far Away von Tristam, Baken
https://soundcloud.com/monstercat/tristam-braken-far-away

Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: Hi Martin, what do you think af the answer given by norcal johnny? Please accept it (if you like it) or comment it to tell your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

It is known as a form of Ambient Classical music. You can also use Googles Free Audio to listen to music.

Simply go to Googles free youtube audio > select Ambient for genre then Calm for mood. You can also select other moods, so in general the genre is Ambient.

https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music